# fsync on newly created folder?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Can anyone explain why fsync can return EINVAL when I pass folder descriptor in it? There is my code, it is pretty simple:

```
#include <dirent.h>     /* Defines DT_* constants */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define handle_error(msg) \
do { trace(msg); exit(0); } while (0)
#define trace printf


int createDir(const char* name) {
    int r = ::mkdir( name, 0777 );
    if (r != 0) {
        trace("error r!=0 %d\n",errno);
    }
    r = open(name, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
    if (r < 0) {
        trace("error create dir r <0\n");
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int r;

    int dir = createDir("test");

    r = fsync(dir);
    trace("r = %d %d\n",r,errno);
    close(dir);


    return 0;
}
```

it gives me this output:

```
r = -1 22
```

I am using linux ver. 2.6.32 (Ubuntu 10.04 as I remember)

So why I got error when I call fsync on folder? When I call fsync with file descriptor passed in, everything is fine

Comment: `perror()` or `strerror()` give you a human-readable error message appropriate for `errno`.

Comment: EINVAL means that a parameter given to a function is not suitable. Is `fsync()` documented to support directory filedescriptors? I guess not. BTW: None of your macros are actually necessary, use inline functions instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: "*Is `fsync()`  documented to support directory filedescriptors?*" Yes, seems so. From Linux's `man fsync()`: "*... an explicit fsync() on a file descriptor for the directory is also
       needed.*"

Comment: Which file-system does the program create the directory in and how is it mounted?

Comment: _"On some UNIX systems (but not Linux), fd must be a writable file descriptor."_ This neither allows nor forbids a descriptor that references a read-only directory. Does opening the directory as read-write make any difference?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I just tried the OP's code on a Wheezy-Debian and could not reproduce the failure. `fsync()` succeeded.

Comment: Interesting, @alk. I just tried the same. First thing I stumbled across is the fact that it doesn't compile as C, not even when removing the `::` from `::open()`. It then still fails to find `O_DIRECTORY`. Then, as C++, it compiles but doesn't fail. Just for the record, that was as normal user on Debian in my home dir with `umask` reporting `0022`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: To have this code compile as C using gcc remove the `::` and add `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I tried open(name, O_RDWR | O_DIRECTORY) and it returns error "Bad file descriptor" I will try that code on newer system, may be it was a bug that fixed for now

Comment: `O_DIRECTORY` is documented as "should not be used outside of the implementation of opendir(3)"... Perhaps you should be using `opendir()` instead...

Comment: @twalberg using opendir() doesn't help me, fsync return "invalid argument" error

Comment: @Lobster What type of file system does this directory reside on? Perhaps that particular file system type does not support `fsync()` on directories...

Comment: @twalberg Thaks you, I finally found the problem! I have ubuntu installed in VirtualBox and my main system is OSX, so I need Linux just to compile programs and check is they works correctly. So I just created shared folder   where I had compiling my programs. So in that shared folder I have not ext4 file system like in system, I have vboxsf file system which do not support fsync on directories! Thank you, I spent more 3 days on that issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was because I have Ubuntu installed in VirtualBox and I run my program from shared folder. VirtualBox shared had vboxsf file system that doesn't support fsync on folder. Thanks for @twalberg